# JsonMethods is not a member of package org.json4s.jackson

Tags: json4s

I'm using json4s in my scala 2.12 application. I added this maven dependency -

`org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:4.0.0`

I have these imports in the code -

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
```

As per the doc, this should work - https://github.com/json4s/json4s

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Comment: parse() function isnt working. Did you figure out ?